# Arquivos com extensão .XLX do excel converteram para extensão .xlx.crypt em meu desktop onde salvo. O que fazer?

Tags: microsoft-excel, arquivo, antivirus

Os arquivos com  extensão em  xlx  em excel passaram para .xlx.crypt. Acho que pegou um virus. Saberiam como remover e não perder os arquivos?
Grato  pela ajuda antecipadamente

Comment: A solução é recuperar os dados de backup, e de preferencia fazer uma cópia do que sobrou intacto, usando outro PC. O _ransomware_ que você pegou vai fazer isso com todos os arquivos seus se continuar deixando o pc ligado (mas não é uma dúvida no escopo do StackOverflow). - Ponha o HD desse PC numa outra máquina que não esteja infectada e faça backup do que sobrou.

Comment: A dúvida é... se perdi os dados pois não tenho o backup destes arquivos.Por isso gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de recuperá-los.

Comment: Pode considerar perdido. Mesmo que pague o resgate que geralmente pedem nesses casos, normalmente nao tem volta.

Comment: Poderia me dizer que virus é esse  Bacco?

Comment: Tem vários desse tipo circulando por aí. E esse ano quem não se preparar tá ferrado, pq as empresas de segurança tão alertando pra uma nova leva mais danosa ainda. Faz tempo que existe esse tipo de malware, mas está aumentando de uma maneira alarmante. Pesquise pelo nome genérico, "ransomware" que vai encontrar material a respeito.

Comment: Muito Obrigado Bacco!

Comment: @JoeliasAndrade pode tentar algo depois para resgatar, mas o Bacco tá certo. Tire esse hd urgente e salve o que puder. Depois tente algum antivirus que tenha decriptografado a versão que pegou. Veja exemplo aqui: https://noransom.kaspersky.com/ Abs e boa sorte!